# Getting Inconsistent accessibility error

Tags: c#

I got a little bit  of a problem and I cant seem to solve it can someone help me,
These are the errors:

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility: field type
>   'Flashloader.Toepassing' is less accessible than field
>   'Flashloader.NewApplication.Toepassing'
>
> Error 2   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type
>   'Flashloader.toepassinginifile' is less accessible than method
>   'Flashloader.NewApplication.NewApplication(Flashloader.toepassinginifile)'

So those where the errors but a source is very useful in this case.

Source 1 New application(This is a Winform):

```
namespace Flashloader{

public partial class NewApplication : Form
{
    private toepassinginifile _toepassinginifile;

    //private controllerinifile _controlIniFile;

    public Toepassing toepassing = new Toepassing();

    public NewApplication(toepassinginifile iniFile)
    {
        _toepassinginifile = iniFile;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Srec Files (.a20; .a21; .a26; .a44)|*.a20; *.a21; *.a26; *.a44|All files (*.*)|*.*";

        openFileDialog1.Title = ("Choose a file");
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            fileBox.Text = (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName));
        }
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        toepassing.Name = nameBox.Text;
        toepassing.Controller = controllerComboBox.SelectedItem;
        toepassing.TabTip = descBox.Text;
        toepassing.Lastfile = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        fileBox.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;


        if (nameBox.Text == "")
            MessageBox.Show("You haven't assigned a Name");
        else if (controllerComboBox.Text == "")
            MessageBox.Show("You haven't assigned a Controller");
        else if (descBox.Text == "")
            MessageBox.Show("You haven't assigned a Desciption");
        else if (fileBox.Text == "")
            MessageBox.Show("You haven't assigned a Applicationfile");
        _toepassinginifile.ToePassingen.Add(toepassing);
        _toepassinginifile.Save();

        MessageBox.Show("Save Succesfull");



        this.Close();
    }

}}
```

Source 2 The flashloader.toepassing file (This is a Class):

```
namespace Flashloader{
class Toepassing
{
    private String _name;

    public String Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public Controller Controller = null;
    public String TabTip = "";
    public String Lastfile = "";

  [Obsolete]
  public String Baudrate = "";

  [Obsolete]
  public String Port = "";

  public String Useboot = "";

    public Toepassing()
    {
        Name = "";
    }

    public Toepassing(String naam)
    {
        Name = naam;
    }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        return Name + " :" + TabTip;
    }
}
}
```

And finally source 3 flashloader.toepassinginifile (Another class):

```
namespace Flashloader
{
class toepassinginifile
{
    private const String FILE_NAME = "flash.ini";
    private Controllerlist _controllers;
    public Toepassinglist ToePassingen { get; private set; }
    public Settings Settings { get; private set; }


    public toepassinginifile( Controllerlist controllers)
    {
        _controllers = controllers;

        // TODO Startup class maken en laden
        ToePassingen = LoadToepassingen();
    }

    private Toepassinglist LoadToepassingen()
    {
        StringList input = new StringList().FromFile( FILE_NAME );
        Toepassinglist output = new Toepassinglist();

        Settings settings = null;
        Toepassing toepassing = null;

        foreach (var item in input)
        {
            String line = item.Trim();

            if (line.StartsWith("[") && line.EndsWith("]"))
            {
                settings = null;
                toepassing = null;

                String name = line.Substring(1, line.Length - 2);

                if (name.ToUpper().Equals("STARTUP"))
                {
                    Settings = settings = new Settings();
                    continue;
                }
                // TODO kan weg in de toekomst
                if ( name.ToUpper().Equals("DRAG && DROP"))
                {
                    toepassing = null;
                    continue;
                } // */

                toepassing = new Toepassing(name);
                output.Add(toepassing);
            }
            else if (settings != null)
            {
                int index = line.IndexOf('=');
                if (index < 0)
                    continue;

                String key = line.Substring(0, index).Trim();
                String value = line.Substring(index + 1).Trim();

                if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "Baudrate"))
                    Settings.Baudrate = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "Port"))
                    Settings.Port = value;
            }
            else if (toepassing != null)
            {
                int index = line.IndexOf('=');
                if (index < 0)
                    continue;

                String key = line.Substring(0, index).Trim();
                String value = line.Substring(index + 1).Trim();

                if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "TabTip"))
                    toepassing.TabTip = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "Controller"))
                    toepassing.Controller = _controllers.FindByName(value);
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "Lastfile"))
                    toepassing.Lastfile = value;
                else if (Utils.EqualsIgnoreCase(key, "Useboot"))
                    toepassing.Useboot = value;
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        StringList list = new StringList();

        Toepassing settings = new Toepassing("[Startup]");

        list.Add("["+settings.Name+"]");
        list.Add("LastUsed=");
        list.Add("Port=" +settings.Port);
        list.Add("Baudrate=" +settings.Baudrate);

        foreach (Toepassing item in ToePassingen)
        {
            list.Add( "[" + item.Name + "]" );
            list.Add( "Controller=" + item.Controller.Name );
            list.Add( "TabTip="+ item.TabTip );
            list.Add("LastFile="+ item.Lastfile);
            list.Add("UseBoot="+ item.Useboot);
        }

        Toepassing dragndrop = new Toepassing("[Drag && Drop]");

            list.Add("["+dragndrop.Name+"]");
            list.Add("Autostart=");
            list.Add("Baudrate="+ dragndrop.Baudrate);
            list.Add("Port="+ dragndrop.Port);
            list.Add("Lasfile="+ dragndrop.Lastfile);

        list.ToFile(FILE_NAME);
    }
}
}
```

If I could get some help, it would be a lot easier to solve the errors.

FIXED IT

Comment: You've missed the important bits, I'm guessing you haven't declared the class `public/internal`, `public class Name`

Comment: @Sayse nice answer^^ bad luck it's a comment

Comment: @WhileTrueSleep - I don't like trying to get reputation by solving very easy questions all day ;) Plus I don't have time while at work to get a full answer made up :)

Comment: May be a detailed explanation will help . Your NewApplicationClass defines a public property ToePassing , it means that everyone who have access to NewApplicationClass will also have access to Toepassing but by default ToePassing access modifier is Internal which means this can be accessed only with in an assembly. So here your contradicting what you wanted (i.e one place you meant public and another you meant internal). So compiler points you that hey ! you are missing something and the same is applicable to toepassinginifile class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `toepassinginifile` is used on a `public` method of a `public` type, it must itself by `public` (it is currently `internal`). Change:

```
class toepassinginifile
```

to:

```
public class toepassinginifile
```

or even better ;p

```
public class ToePassingIniFile
```

and likewise for the other, since `Toepassing` is used as a `public` field on a `public` type, `Toepassing` must itself be `public`.

Final thought: `public` fields are rarely a good idea; a `public` *property* would be preferable:

```
private Toepassing toepassing = new Toepassing();
public Toepassing Toepassing  {get { return toepassing; } }
```

Comment: When i did this i got 5 errors extra and then the other function won't work

Comment: I'd happily +2 for "even better" : )

Comment: @Collin.Koornstra well, unless you tell me what the 5 extra errors are, I can't really comment

Comment: ok i i deleted them but i will make it so that they come back

Comment: @Collin.Koornstra - this **is** what your errors in this question are referring to, your new errors are probably just new valid errors that were previously covered up

Comment: Error 1: Error 3 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'Flashloader.Controllerlist' is less accessible than method 'Flashloader.toepassinginifile.toepassinginifile(Flashloader.Controllerlist)' C:\Projects\flashloader2013\mainapplication\toepassinginifile.cs 17 16 Main

Comment: @Collin.Koornstra - Go through your different classes and apply this **same** solution to every one of these errors

Comment: Error 2: Error 2 Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'Flashloader.Settings' is less accessible than property 'Flashloader.toepassinginifile.Settings' C:\Projects\flashloader2013\mainapplication\toepassinginifile.cs 14 25 Main

Comment: Error 3 Error 4 Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'Flashloader.Toepassing' is less accessible than property 'Flashloader.NewApplication.Toepassing' C:\Projects\flashloader2013\mainapplication\NewApplication.cs 20 27 Main

Comment: And the last one: Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'Flashloader.Toepassinglist' is less accessible than property 'Flashloader.toepassinginifile.ToePassingen' C:\Projects\flashloader2013\mainapplication\toepassinginifile.cs 13 31 Main

Answer (score 1):

Add public before the declaration of your class.
Your first class are public so Toepassinginifile and Toepassing have to be public too.

Comment: @Collin.Koornstra actually, that is *the* solution to the problem; what I suspect you mean is "there are other problems which don't get observed until I fix this" - in which case : you'll have to tell us *what*, exactly

Answer (score 1):

The errors you are getting are saying that you won't be able to use your public methods from your class as the class is marked as private

By default classes are internal

```
class ClassName
{
public void Method()
```

The above will error as you can never call method becausethe class has less accessibility than the method

```
private bool Property {get; public set;}
```

willl probably also error

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

Comment: by default class is internal but not private